# View Source on File Double-Click?

Tags: intellij-idea

I added `Foo.scala` as a new Scala class within my `IntelliJ 14.1` project:

```
class Foo 
object Foo
```

When I click on this file once in IntelliJ, it expands the Class and Object:

[image]

I find it to be a hassle to have to click the file (`Foo.scala`), and then double-click the Object/Class to view the source.

How can I configure IntelliJ to open the source file once I double-click on the file name, i.e. `Foo.scala` per this example?

Comment: I'd say: don't use the mouse. Or even better; don't use the project view at all. Use ⌘n to open the file, or double shift.

Comment: @ErikPragt 1. why not use the mouse? 2. It's still relevant with the keyboard (I would expect <Enter> to "Jump to source"). 3. Why the hell should you not use the project view? It's like someone asking "how can I build a kitchen for my house?" and you say "just buy the entire house".

Comment: This isn't a Scala specific problem. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417206/intellij-project-view-not-show-multiple-classes-in-same-file

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Please file an issue at [JetBrains](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com) if you want to have this improved.